# Multiple Http request in a single thread

Tags: java, multithreading, http

Its a simple question i am trying to understand for my project.

I need to Open 10000 http requests in a single thread.

I was wondering since I have never done something like that, if it is possible, and if i should encounter any problems doing so.

ty.

Comment: Well, DNS lookups could be interesting on async.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you need to use non-blocking IO. Look at Http components http://hc.apache.org/